# Available Inventory not showing with product info

Tags: inventory, out-of-stock, list.phtml

So I am trying to get the available inventory to show in the product info on the product list. So like it would have the price then Available inventory right below it. I was looking for solutions online but not of them seemed to work (whenever i tried an example it wouldn't show and product or would just show an error message).

I noticed that people were saying if you set 'Display products availability in stock in the frontend' in system->configuration->inventory to YES then it would displays an availability message indicating the product stock status. I have it set to yes, however it does not say if it is ever in stock, only if it is out of stock.

People were also saying that this was all programmed in /app/design/frontend/XXX/YYY/template/catalog/product/list.html. I looked in there and none of the code looks like it would do this. So if anyone has a way to display the Available Inventory it would be much appreciated.

Update:
I found a code that used getQty() but it did not work (it printed 0 for every product).

Update: The answer below works but has decimal places. To remove those decimals I used round(). So the final code I used was:

```
$num= Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); 
$num = round($num);
echo "Remaining products: ".$num;
```

Comment: You can control if products with no stock are displayed or not. This is a setting in the adminhtml backend (somewhere). So stock availability can control a certain amount of output. You find this behavior hardencoded, partially in INNER JOINs on index tables but also with IF CLAUSES wihthin controller and template code. So probably it is not as easy/straight forward as one might think on first glance. Also take care with resources you find online: Often they are for specific cases and might not cover your case. But still read them as they contain hints and pointers.

Comment: With available inventory do you meant the numeric amount in the inventory?

Comment: Yes I wish to show the numeric amount. And I am aware of showing or not showing items out of stock. Thanks

Comment: Okay, were you able to locate the *out of stock* message you experienced in the front within your templates? There is some template logic over there IIRC because you can also control what availability means (e.g. not available if less than X or so).

Comment: Yeah I am able to display 'out of stock' if the product is out of stock. Its when the product is in stock I want it to say how many are left in stock. I am guessing the solution would include an api call to magento in catalog/product/list.phtml

Comment: And could you locate the source of that message in templates? e.g. by removing it for a test to know you've located the place in the template? And you don't do API calls to phtml files, phtml files are for the templating. But it helps if you locate the responsible template first.

Comment: I have located the source yes

Comment: Ah and just a short note: There is a field named "stock_data[is_in_stock]" ('Stock Availability') which is yes/no only. But you're looking for  "stock_data[qty]" ('Qty') which is the stock quantity. Depending on what you've got, there are implications on simple, grouped and configurable products when you do a listing.

Comment: As you have located the source, about which file (relative to your projects root) and line are you talking about?

Comment: /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Comment: <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>(line 179-181)

Comment: There should be something like `$_product->getStockItem()` above it, right? If you set a breakpoint there and evaluate that expression you should find anything you need to obtain the number (quantity) you're looking for. All you need to do is edit the template there. What's your experience with a step-debugger like xdebug?

Comment: getStockItem() is not in this file. Ill put that in and see if that helps. And ive never used a step-debuger.

Comment: I put that in and print_r the array and it was:  
 Varien_Object Object
(
    [_data:protected] = Array
        (
            [is_in_stock] = 1
        )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] =
    [_origData:protected] =
    [_idFieldName:protected] = 
    [_isDeleted:protected] =
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] = Array
        (
        )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] =  Array
        (
        )
)

Comment: Hmm, I have it in that file. Which Magento version are you using?

Comment: 1.9.0.1 I believe

Comment: I have a 1.9.1.0 here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get the inventory of the product anywhere, try below code

```
<?php 
    $num= Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); 
    echo "Remaining products: ".$num;
?>
```